# Laravel collection Group by with json

Tags: laravel, collections

I have an students table like:

| id | name | father_details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | {"father_email":"abc@example.com", "father_name":"Pietro Hoeger"} |
| 2 | B | {"father_email":"abcd@example.com", "father_name":"Jace Bayer"} |
| 3 | C | {"father_email":"abce@example.com", "father_name":"Pietro Hoeger"} |
| 4 | D | {"father_email":"abcf@example.com", "father_name":"Pietro Hoeger"} |

I want to try group by father name from json:

```
$students = Student::get()
    ->groupBy('father_details->father_name'); // This Group by is not working
```

But the father name is not group by in key what can i do for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`->groupBy()` as you're using it is a `Collection` method, which accepts a `string` for the property/attribute you wish to group by. It is not a builder method, so it has no idea that `'father_details->father_name'` is supposed to be evaluating the JSON, and `$student['father_details->father_name']` is definitely not valid. So yeah, `->groupBy('father_details->father_name')` is not going to work.

If you check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-groupby) You can use a `callback` function instead of a `string`.

If your `Student` Model is properly handling `father_details` as JSON and converting it to an object automatically:

```
$students = Student::get()->groupBy(function ($student) {
  return $student->father_details->father_name;
});
```

If your model is not doing that automatically, then you'll need to do it manually:

```php
$students = Student::get()->groupBy(function ($student) {
  return json_decode($student->father_details)->father_name;
});
```

Or similar. This should group your data, one group for `Pietro Hoeger` and another group for `Jace Bayer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$students = Student::select('father_details->father_name as father_name')->groupBy('father_name')->get();`

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/can-i-group-by-a-json-property